# Tilemap not getting loaded in Phaser

Tags: javascript, json, phaser-framework

I am trying make a game using a tilemap in Phaser. I am following the steps shown in the example "Load Tilemap with json" available with Phaser.

```js
var game=new Phaser.Game(800,600,Phaser.AUTO,'',{ preload:preload,create:create,update:update });

function preload(){
    game.load.tilemap('map','m4.json',null,Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
    game.load.image('fruits','M484GoodFruits.png');
}

var map;
var layer;
function create(){
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#787878';
    map = game.add.tilemap('map');

    map.addTilesetImage('tiles','fruits');    

     layer = map.createLayer('my_terrain');

    layer.resizeWorld();
    layer.wrap = true;
}

function update(){
}
```

However, the tilemap is not loaded and I am getting the following error:

> Error: WebGL: texImage2D: Chosen format/type incured an expensive reformat: 0x1908/0x1401phaser.min.js:4:26133
>
> GET 
>   XHR 
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/maze/m4.json [HTTP/1.0 200 OK 10ms]
>
> GET 
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/maze/M484GoodFruits.png [HTTP/1.0 200 OK 6ms]
>
> TypeError: x is undefined
>   [Learn More]

When I click on Learn more, I am redirected to a page talking about TypeError. I do not know how to resolve this issue because I am a beginner in Phaser. I am quite disappointed at being stuck at the same point for a couple of days now. Please point out what I am doing wrong. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the code is ok the problem problem might be inside json I think by the way these links are not working.

Comment: Can you open this tilemap in the Tiled editor? That might help zero in.